# mbed socket connection takes a long time

Tags: c++, sockets, timeout, mbed

I'm fighting with my Mbed controller and it's winning :/
Part of my code below:

```
eth.connect();
pc.printf("ethernet OK");
sock.set_blocking(false,200);
pc.printf(" socket setting OK ");
sock.connect("192.168.1.100", 80);
pc.printf("GO! GO! GO!");
conn = sock.is_connected();
```

When the server is on I can connect with socket and there is no problem. But when I shut my server down, my program wait in sock.connect(...) line for a long time and then it moves forward. I want it to move forward, but I don't want to wait such a long time :/

I found that I should change socket setting from blocking to non-blocking, and timeout from default=1500 to less. I changed it everywhere I could:
 - Part of my socket.h library:
`void set_blocking(bool blocking, unsigned int timeout=200);`
 - Part of my socket.cpp library:
`Socket::Socket() : _sock_fd(-1), _blocking(false), _timeout(200)`
 And still nothing. It wait about 17-18sec, but I would like to change it to max. 1-2sec. 
I would be glad, if you give me an any tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I need to say, that TCP_SYNMAXRTX changing is something, what can really help, it helped me, but not at all. In my case the important was to change mbed OS to the latest version. In previous there was libraries with socket settings, but actually they work properly since mbed OS contains EthernetInterface and others libraries (you shouldn't import it as external library).

Thank you for your time and goodwill! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using mbed OS, set the socket to blocking and set the timeout to whatever you think is appropriate. No modifications are necessary. The method syntax can be seen [here](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/features/netsocket/Socket.h#L96-L121).

However, I am having trouble reproducing your issue. Can you use a debugger and confirm if the application is hanging at this line - https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/533e6f0febb5ea582a61f0c8aaf686c70333524f/features/netsocket/TCPSocket.cpp#L57?

Comment: Hello Sarah :) I use different library - I just imported EthernetInteface and there I found Socket and others files, but the copyright is from 2012 and source code looks differently. Is it any other library, which I should download? Maybe it is some kind of "not smart" question, but I'm very new in mbed programming :)

You're asking about TCPSocket.cpp, but in EthernetInterface that file even doesn't exist, so I suppose it should be something else. Could you say me what I should look for? I uploaded the most fresh EthernetInterface, but it is still the same.

Comment: After editing: I use Socket from: https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/Socket and it is actually very analogic. I tried to set it to blocking=true, timeout=200 and many other combinations, but still nothing :/

Comment: Switch to mbed OS 5. EthernetInterface is included in there. The EthernetInterface library you mentioned is not supported anymore. Start by cloning https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-blinky, then add the same code. This way you should have the latest and greatest releases, and it will probably work.

Comment: The example shown here - https://docs.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os-api-reference/en/latest/APIs/communication/ethernet/ would be a better jumping off point. Clone this and look around. You'll notice there are no extraneous libraries outside of mbed OS.

Answer (score 0):

marshmallow's suggestion should be fine.

Theoretically you could also try and set the [TCP_SYNMAXRTX](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/92073650eabb21e87438d482313cb6eb74ab5bb4/features/FEATURE_LWIP/lwip-interface/lwip/src/include/lwip/opt.h#L1166) macro to something lower. It might have some other unforeseen consequences though (which I'm not sure off, as I don't know much about LwIP).

Comment: Hello Jan ;)
I've changed this makro as you said - I like risk and I set it to "1". I saw, that when I put the card close to RFID reader it pushes data pretty fast (it stops for 3sec, not for 18sec - and it's OK for me), but when I put next card it behaves the same as before - 18sec waiting. So after restart, first data goes OK, but next is blocking as before. Is there any buffor to clear?